# Is there an SSD Benchmark Tool for Linux to measure speed vs time or speed vs space usage?

Tags: linux, files, ssd, software-rec, benchmark

Most of the SSD benchmarks you see out there use solely Crystal Disk Mark for Windows on an empty SSD. This allows to show speeds of 300~550MB/s (SATAIII), which is amazing compared to most HDDs.

However, there are some cases where this trend is overestimated or even in reverse. Take a look:

[image: imgur picture]

To do this test, people usually copy several GBs in Windows and plot the transfer speed.

I'm aware of several tools in Linux to benchmark disks (ex: hdparm, dd, GNOME disks, fio, kdiskmark, ...). However, I don't know of a tool in Linux that makes the above graph (ie: speed vs time).

**Question**
Is there a tool in Linux to measure **speed vs time** or **speed vs space usage**?

Comment: You could use `pv -petrab /dev/zero > $HOME/tmp.file`. This will show write speed in real time.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Is it possible to save such data points (ie: speed, time, space usage) into a file?

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible but you could try `pv -petrab /dev/zero > $HOME/tmp.file 2> /tmp/pv.log`  If that doesn't work you'll need something different, only I don't know what. I've never needed this info.

Comment: @ArtemS.Tashkinov Although `pv` seems to be a good and lightweight solution, I'm more inclined to dig deeper `fio`. I've just read that it can do exactly what I mentioned in the OP: _"Fio records a 'performance trace' of various metrics, such as IOPs and latency over time in plain-text .log files."_